# PHP Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, centos, apache2

Saludo

Este error me sale en mi instancia EC2 de Centos.

> PHP Warning:  date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings.
>
> You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone

Mi versión de PHP es 5.6.35

Ya modifiqué el archivo php.ini y quedo así:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Bogota
```

Luego reinicié apache y aún me sale el mismo error.

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Justo antes de que establezcas date.timezone, necesitas declarar

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
```

Luego reiniciar y probar si ya funciona

Comment: Pregunta, esto lo declaro en php.ini, o en el archivo que usa la función date()?

Comment: en tu archivo que usa la función date